# Granular permissions in Firestore with service accounts

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am writing a tool that gathers information from diagnostic packages. Results from this tool are written into Firestore for analytics. The tool is written in Python and distributed as a Package, including the .json for a service account. That service account is use to authenticate read + writes from the database. Below is a snippet from the database component used in each package:

```
    import firebase_admin
    from firebase_admin import credentials
    from firebase_admin import firestore

    cred=credentials.Certificate(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__), 'name_of_file.json'))
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

    db = firestore.client()
```

I am looking to narrow down permissions for Firestore, as currently, all users with these credentials have full access to Firestore. Looking at the docs, it appears this may not be possible:

> Code that uses the Firebase Admin SDK with a service account to access Firestore currently can not be scoped to a particular user ID for the purpose of enforcing security rules. All access with the Admin SDK will bypass security rules and have full control of the database.

Does anyone know a workaround for this kind of use case? As an alternative, is it possible to "hard code" a Firebase user account? If so, what would be the most straightforward implementation?

Please let me know if there is anything I can clarify, I am fairly new to Firebase, so I may be going in the complete wrong direction!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore currently currently doesn't have a way to scope a connection using a service account to some limited permissions.  When using the Admin SDK, you will always have full read and write access to the entire database.  This is a commonly requested feature, and you should [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features) if this is also useful for you.

Comment: Thank you for getting back, I'll get a feature request submitted! Do you know of any methods of hard-coding a non-service account for use? I am looking thru the documentation, but coming up short. This sounds like something straightforward enough to implement, but I can't seem to find. Any advice / insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The admin SDK doesn't doesn't have a way to simulate a user login.

Comment: Anything new or any possibility to do that nowadays?